# How to append a string to the end of a given line in LUA?

Tags: string, lua, append

I have a working function with 3 parameters.

```
function file.append(filename, linha, texto)
    filename = file.checkname(filename)
    if file.exists(filename) then  

    local hFile = io.open(filename, "r") --Reading.
    local lines = {}
    local restOfFile
    local lineCt = 1
    for line in hFile:lines() do
    if(lineCt == linha) then --Is this the line to modify?
        lines[#lines + 1] = line .. " " .. texto --Modify line by appending a string to the end.
        restOfFile = hFile:read("*a")
        break
    else
        lineCt = lineCt + 1
        lines[#lines + 1] = line
    end
    end
    hFile:close()

    hFile = io.open(filename, "w") --Write the file.
    for i, line in ipairs(lines) do
        hFile:write(line, "\n")
    end
    hFile:write(restOfFile)
    hFile:close()

    end -- end file.exists()
end
```

The problem with this function is that it reads the entire .txt file and then rewrites line by line, appending "text" to the specified "line", with everything else being being unaltered.

Because it reads and then rewrites the entire .txt file, it can fail to write to the file, leaving it empty. This rarely happens, but when it does, I lose everything.

I need a function to simply append to the end of a given line without rewriting the whole file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: First safety step: Use a temporary file for your output and only rename on top if the line count makes sense and the write works. Also you can read and write in one loop instead of collecting the lines into a table (and have much better memory behaviour).

Comment: @Etan Reisner Writing to a secondary file and then checking if the number of lines match, that's a good idea. I suppose it's not possible to append to the end of a specified line without rewriting the entire file. Or is it?

Comment: Your read loop also terminates as soon as the line is found, is that intentional? You truncate your file at the line you found.

Comment: You need to rewrite everything after the modification. Technically you don't need to rewrite anything before that if you are operating in place (you aren't). And I didn't mean count the output file lines I meant check the table size against the count of lines you read (or whatever). Though checking the actual written file is also a reasonable (if costlier) idea.